# Discover the origin of "untrusted" events

Tags: javascript, security, dom-events

I've done a little Javascript library that should help tracking (and preventing) fraudulent behavior on a web page. It has various functionalities and one of them is to track any `evt.isTrusted = false` on the page, sending also the `evt.target` to my logs.

Everything is working fine and I already found some suspicious patterns, which was the goal to achieve. Now, the question is:

is there a way to understand "what" originated those untrusted event on the page?

I'm supposing that there is some Javascript involved, of course something injected somehow (I'm thinking actually to some browser extension), and anything I can gather can help me hugely, I mean, the function name, the function library name, or any other information, have you got any idea?